# Как разукрасить плейсхолдер инпута в разные цвета

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

К примеру есть input, внутри "Имя" серым, а звездочку красным, как это реализовать ?

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Имя*">
```

Comment: В данном примере никак. Только имитировать плейсхолдер другим элементом + js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

.form-item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-item input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.form-item label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.form-item label>span {
  color: #f00;
}

.form-item input:valid+label,
.form-item input:focus+label {
  opacity: 0;
}

button {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-item">
    <input type="text" id="fname" required>
    <label for="fname">Name <span>*</span></label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Button submit</button>
</form>
```